# "My feet came up out of the sand" vs. "I took my feet out of the sand"

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> My feet came up out of the sand.
>   I took my feet out of the sand.

Which sentence is better? Why?
What are the differences between these sentences?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are correct and neither  is better than  the other. They just have different meanings.

> My feet came up out of the sand.

This implies that someone was raised  up out of the sand. They could have pulled themselves up using their arms, or perhaps be sitting in a chair and pulled their feet up, or someone pulled them up. We just know that both feet came out of the sand, which implies, that perhaps they were not standing on them when this happened!

> I took my feet out of  the sand.

This certainly confirms that no-one else was involved, but how this was achieve we do not know.

So, the first sentence could involve other people or machines and the second could only involve the person.